# How to call the VBA codes to Command button?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am having some vba codes, but i have to run this code by command button.
i have drawn a cmd button in a form. But how to call the code?

the code is:

```
   Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^p^p"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
.
.
.
```

Comment: on `Commandbutton Click` event perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

While designing the UserForm, double-click the CommandButton, or right-click it and select "View Code":

[image]

This will take you to the code editor. Edit the `CommandButton1_Click` (where CommandButton1 is the codename of your button).

[image]

Here I just wrote a dummy example:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox "you clicked the button"
End Sub
```

but you can add whatever code you like, such as calling the sub you have already written.